# AJAX Control Toolkit MultiHandleSlider readOnly handle

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a question about AJAX MultiHandleSliderExtender. Code is following:

```
<form runat="server" id="myForm">
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server" CombineScripts="false" />

<asp:TextBox ID="strMinModTB" runat="server" Style="display:none;" Text="80" />  
<asp:TextBox ID="strCurModTB" runat="server" Style="display:none;" Text="100" />  
<asp:TextBox ID="strMaxModTB" runat="server" Style="display:none;" Text="160" />  
<asp:TextBox ID="strSlider" runat="server" Style="display:none;" />  

<asp:MultiHandleSliderExtender ID="strModMultiSlider" runat="server"  
            BehaviorID="strModMultiSlider"  
            TargetControlID="strSlider"  
            Minimum="0"  
            Maximum="300"  
            Length="600"  
            EnableHandleAnimation="true"  
            EnableKeyboard="false"  
            EnableMouseWheel="false"  
            ShowInnerRail="true"  
            ShowHandleDragStyle="true"
            ShowHandleHoverStyle="true">  
            <MultiHandleSliderTargets>                  
                <asp:MultiHandleSliderTarget ControlID="strMinModTB" />  
                <asp:MultiHandleSliderTarget ControlID="strCurModTB" />  
                <asp:MultiHandleSliderTarget ControlID="strMaxModTB" />  
            </MultiHandleSliderTargets>              
</asp:MultiHandleSliderExtender>

<asp:Label ID="sliderLabel" runat="server" Visible="true"></asp:Label>
</form>
```

Now what I want to do is to lock positions of outter handles and allow only the middle one to be dragged in range from the left hanle to the right one thus changing the value in asp:Label (ID="sliderLabel").

I've tried readOnly="true" attribute on TextBoxes but with no result. There is also IsReadOnly Extender property but that blocks all handles.

Also when I add the BoundControlID property (containing ID of label) to the Extender it stops working (all handles on 0 position and I cannot drag them)

Is there a way around this or am I missing something?

Thank you for replies :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a BoundControlID for the MHSE do you?

Also, could you not add a class to each Handle and then fix the outer handles positions using CSS?

See below for code example.

**ASP Code**

```
<asp:MultiHandleSliderExtender ID="strModMultiSlider" runat="server"  
            BehaviorID="strModMultiSlider" TargetControlID="strSlider"  
            Minimum="0" Maximum="300" Length="600"  
            EnableHandleAnimation="true" EnableKeyboard="false"  
            EnableMouseWheel="false" ShowInnerRail="true"  
            ShowHandleDragStyle="true" ShowHandleHoverStyle="true">  
            <MultiHandleSliderTargets>                  
                <asp:MultiHandleSliderTarget ControlID="strMinModTB" HandleCssClass="handle_outer"/>  
                <asp:MultiHandleSliderTarget ControlID="strCurModTB" HandleCssClass="handle_inner" />  
                <asp:MultiHandleSliderTarget ControlID="strMaxModTB" HandleCssClass="handle_outer"/>  
            </MultiHandleSliderTargets>              
</asp:MultiHandleSliderExtender>
```

**CSS Code**

```
.handle_outer
{   
   //Code to Fix Handle in Place  
}

.handle_inner
{
}
```